# count the number of ways in which N persons form pair

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

This is the question.

In code world all genders are considered equal ( It means their is nothing like male or female). Now their are N distinct persons living in this hypothetical world. Each person can pair up with any other person or can even remain single.
One day Vbhu planned to visit code world. Being a maths guy , he always try to be mathematical. So he started counting the ways in which N persons living in code world can make pairs or remain single. A single person can make pair with at most one other person.
Seeing that N can be large , Vibhu ask you for help. Now being a great programmer you need to help Vbhu count the number of ways in which N persons living in code world can make pairs or remain single.

question link = `https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/dynamic-programming/introduction-to-dynamic-programming-1/practice-problems/algorithm/vibhu-and-his-mathematics/description/`

editorial solution :

Let F(X) denote the number of ways for the above problem, meaning we have X number of people. So, Lets tak about Xth person, he might like to remain single or he can pair up with some person from [1,X-1].

So, considering and adding both the cases to the final answer, we get the recurrence:-
F(X) = F(X-1) + (X-1)*F(X-2). Lets look at the pseudo code for the implementation of recursive approach.

I understand the case where he remains single(f(x-1)) but for the other case, the total possible way to pick other partner is x-1 but why multiply by f(x-2)

Answer (score 1):

About the other case where the person wants to pair up: In this case after choosing a person to pair with, the remaining persons are `X-2` for which the answer is `F(X-2)`.

There are `X-1` ways to choose a partner. For each option of choosing a partner, there are `F(X-2)` ways and for `(X-1)` options - total ways are `(X-1)*F(X-2)`.